# sqlalchemy + flask , getting all post by day

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a table,  `posts`.

which consist of :

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(200))
content =  db.Column(db.Text())
time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

this is what I am trying to achieve when I navigate to this url.

`/allposts`

```
posts on 01-01-2013
 - post 1
 - post 2
 - post 3 

posts on 01-02-2013
 - post 4
 - post 5
 - post 6
```

and so on.

I have tried group by but I couldn't achieve what I explained above.

I am using sqlalchemy and flask python framework.

providing both , raw and sqlalhemy queries will be much better so I can wrap my head around some of the concepts here.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the whole model definition? I assume `time` is a `datetime`?

Comment: @DazWorrall yes, I updated the question with the Model Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do it in a query, but rather create desired grouping on the python side:

```
# get desired posts (add your filters etc)
posts = session.query(Post).order_by(Post.time)

# create a dictionary, where key is the date(-only), and values are the posts of that day
from collections import defaultdict
grouped = defaultdict(list)
for post in posts:
    dat = post.time.date()
    grouped[dat].append(post)

# iterate over new grouped structure
for dat, posts in sorted(grouped.items()):
    print dat
    for post in posts:
        print '  ', post
```