# sqlalchemy return query grouped to user_id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Example model:

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
```

return list with objects grouped to user_id's

required sample output:

```
[(5, [<dal.model.order.Orders object at 0x7fc17770f240>, <dal.model.order.Orders object at 0x7fc17770f2b0>]),
(8, [<dal.model.order.Orders object at 0x7fc14470f270>])]
# 5 and 8 are user_id's
```

Need sqlalchemy query to get output as above.

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731361/sqlalchemy-group-by-with-full-child-objects, and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737228/sqlalchemy-group-by-day-over-multiple-tables

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029101/sqlalchemy-flask-getting-all-post-by-day, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918946/sqlalchemy-querying-all-objects-with-no-direct-relationship

Answer (score 1):

That is not a task for group by. Group by will allow you perform aggregation.

Here you could for example loop through the result and build a dictionary (such as d = collections.defaultdict(list), d[result.user_id].append(result)) which you can later easily covert to a list.